# Find the indefinite integral of $\int \sqrt{1 -\frac{1-\cos (x)}{z(x-\sin(x))}}{dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am currently trying to find the indefinite integral

$$\int \sqrt{1 -\frac{1-\cos (x)}{z(x-\sin(x))}}{dx} $$ where $z$ is a constant. I have not been able to make any progress, and have tried checking tables of integrals and other relevant resources, but none of these appear to provide me with an answer. How would any of you go about solving this integral?

Comment: Do you know for sure that this has an elementary answer?

Comment: Do you seriously expect this to have a closed form???

Comment: @Tavish I do not think this has an elementary answer but wanted to check in case I perhaps overlooked something.

Comment: Have you tried using WolframAlpha, for example?

Comment: Yes, but it does not provide me with an answer (it exceeds standard computation time).

Comment: Then that integral is probably not doable.

Comment: Alright, thanks!